# Why does dereferencing avoid borrow in closure

Tags: rust, closures, borrow-checker

This code

```rust
fn broken(xs: &Vec<f32>) -> Vec<f32> {
    xs.iter()
        .flat_map(|x| xs.iter().map(|y| x - y))
        .collect()
}
```

gives me the error

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `x`, which is owned by the current function
```

I understand why this is unsafe. However, I do not understand why writing `*x` fixes the issue. Does this force a copy?

```rust
fn working(xs: &Vec<f32>) -> Vec<f32> {
    xs.iter()
        .flat_map(|x| xs.iter().map(|y| *x - y))
        .collect()
}
```

Comment: Yes, it forces a copy. If the type if `*x` weren't `Copy`, this would be an error "cannot move out of shared reference", and since it is, the compiler is allowed (and required) to copy.

Comment: You could also do `.map(move |y| x - y)` to have the closure move/take ownership of `x` from its environment rather than only have a shared reference from which it copies.